# Erro na passagem de Date como parametro

Tags: php, php-7

Estou criando uma **classe** com **métodos** **parametrizados**.

Os **dados** são **fictícios**:

```
<?php

    require_once '../../../erros.php';


    class ClientesModelos {

        private $idClientes, $data, $nome, $sobreNome, $nascimento, $documento, $telefone, $celular, $email, $senha, $bloqueio;

        public function __construct (
            date $_data, 
            string $_nome, 
            string $_sobreNome, 
            date $_nacimento, 
            int $_documento, 
            int $_telefone, 
            bool $_celular, 
            string $_email,
            string $_senha,  
            bool $_bloqueio = false
        ) {         
            $this->data        = $_data;
            $this->nome        = $_nome;
            $this->sobreNome   = $_sobreNome;
            $this->nascimento  = $_nacimento;   
            $this->documento   = $_documento;
            $this->telefone    = $_telefone;
            $this->celular     = $_celular;
            $this->email       = $_email;       
            $this->senha       = $_senha;       
            $this->bloqueio    = $_bloqueio;        
        }       

        public function setIdClientes(int $_idClientes) { $this->idClientes = $_idClientes; }

        public function getIdClientes() : int { return $this->idClientes; }

        public function getData() : string { return $this->data; }

        public function getNome() : string { return $this->nome; }

        public function getSobreNome() : string { return $this->sobreNome; }

        public function getNascimento() : date { return $this->nascimento; }

        public function getDocumento() : int {  return $this->documento; }

        public function getTelefone() : int { return $this->telefone; }

        public function getCelular() : ?bool { return $this->celular ? $this->email : NULL; }

        public function getEmail() : string { return $this->email; }

        public function getSenha() : string { return $this->senha; }

        public function getBloqueio() : string { return $this->bloqueio; }

}


$clientesModelos =  new ClientesModelos(
      date('Y-m-d'),
     'Carlos',
     'Alberto',
     date('1970-12-20'),
     77777777777,
     12345678,
     87654321,
     'carcleo@oi.com.br',
     'aaaa',
     false 
 );


print_r ($clientesModelos);
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte **erro**:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ClientesModelos::__construct() must be an instance of date, string given, called in 
D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos.php on line 71 and defined in 
D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos.php:10 Stack trace: #0 
D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos.php(71): 
ClientesModelos->__construct('2019-05-02', 'Carlos', 'Alberto', '1970-12-20', 77777777777, 12345678, 87654321, 'carcleo@oi.com....', 'aaaa', false) #1 {main} thrown in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos.php on line 10
```

Mas eu estou passando data corretamente.

Comment: E o que deveria ser o tipo `date`? Você está passando uma *string*.

Comment: Acho que não: date("Y-m-d") e date ("1970-12-20"). Onde está meu erro no raciocínio?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-returnvalues

Comment: Hum, seria o caso então de eu trocar para string? Ou teria que mudar o parâmtro passado?]

Comment: O erro é que `date` não é um tipo e o que você está passando como parâmetro é o retorno da função, que é uma *string*.

Comment: O correto seria então trocar por string e tratar no corpo da função?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php), assim você pode definir o tipo

```
class ClientesModelos {

    private $idClientes, $data, $nome, $sobreNome, $nascimento, $documento, $telefone, $celular, $email, $senha, $bloqueio;

    public function __construct (
        DateTime $_data, 
        string $_nome, 
        string $_sobreNome, 
        DateTime $_nacimento, 
        int $_documento, 
        int $_telefone, 
        bool $_celular, 
        string $_email,
        string $_senha,  
        bool $_bloqueio = false
    ) {         
        $this->data        = $_data;
        $this->nome        = $_nome;
        $this->sobreNome   = $_sobreNome;
        $this->nascimento  = $_nacimento;   
        $this->documento   = $_documento;
        $this->telefone    = $_telefone;
        $this->celular     = $_celular;
        $this->email       = $_email;       
        $this->senha       = $_senha;       
        $this->bloqueio    = $_bloqueio;        
    }       

    public function setIdClientes(int $_idClientes) { $this->idClientes = $_idClientes; }

    public function getIdClientes() : int { return $this->idClientes; }

    public function getData() : string { return $this->data; }

    public function getNome() : string { return $this->nome; }

    public function getSobreNome() : string { return $this->sobreNome; }

    public function getNascimento() : string{ return $this->nascimento->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'); }

    public function getDocumento() : int {  return $this->documento; }

    public function getTelefone() : int { return $this->telefone; }

    public function getCelular() : ?bool { return $this->celular ? $this->email : NULL; }

    public function getEmail() : string { return $this->email; }

    public function getSenha() : string { return $this->senha; }

    public function getBloqueio() : string { return $this->bloqueio; }

}


$clientesModelos =  new ClientesModelos(
    new DateTime('now'),
    'Carlos',
    'Alberto',
    new DateTime('1970-12-20'),
    1234,
    1234,
    1234,
    'carcleo@oi.com.br',
    'aaaa',
    false 
);


print_r ($clientesModelos);
```

Comment: e no getData() eu retiro apenas a data né?

Comment: Tem que usar o objeto, formatando a data conforme você quer, usando `->format()`

Comment: tentei assim na hora de popular o objeto mas não funcionou $this->data        = $_data->date; Pois ó preciso da data mesmo para guardar no banco

Comment: use `->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: assim ->format('Y-m-d') será que dá?

Comment: funcionou! Obrigado!

Comment: hum, fui fazer dessa forma $this->data        = new DateTime('now')->format('Y-m-d'); e não deu.

Comment: dessa forma da erro, é nessa classe que você tentou fazer isso?

Comment: isso mas lembrei do famoso $this->data        = date('Y-m-d');

Comment: Se quiser passar o formato direto com `DateTime`, pode fazer assim `(new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d')`